# How do I find the number of solutions of the equation $r_1 + r_2 + .... + r_k = n$

Tags: permutations, combinations, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I was studying the multinomial theorem:
$(u_1+u_1+...u_k)^n=\sum\limits_{r_1+r_2+...r_k=n}\dfrac{n!}{r_1!r_2!...r_k!}u_1^{r_1}u_2^{r_2}...u_k^{r_k}$

and my book said that the number of terms in the expansion of a polynomial using the multinomial theorem is equal to the the number of solutions of

the equation  $r_1 + r_2 + .... + r_k = n$

$n \in N$;

$0\leq r_i \leq n $;
$r_i \in W$;
$i=0,1,2,..,k$;

I know that the answer to this is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ but I do not know how to get this result. Please help me out here.

Comment: You can take a look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one).

Answer (score 0):

It can be put like this
You want to put n like things in k baskets
So there will be $ k-1$ barriers 
and the permutations of n like objects and $k-1$ barriers are
$$ \frac{^{n+k-1}P_{k-1}}{n!} $$
Which is 
$$ ^{n+k-1}C_{k-1} $$